# typecasting PyArrayObject data to a C array

Tags: python, numpy, python-c-api

I want to work with my Numpy arrays in a C extension.
Many examples in this case uses the structure of PyArrayObject,

`array->data , array->strides[0] , array->strides[1] , ...`

pointers in order to reach the data, if I wanted to reach my array in a more familiar (or tidier) way to me, with indices like

`array[i][j]`

how should I proceed so? Should I typecast (bool *) array->data and work with the C array I created? (my elements are bools)

My function declaration for now is (not finished, of course)

```
static PyObject *
xor_masking(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{

PyObject *input;
PyObject *mask;
PyObject *adjacency;
PyObject *state;
PyArrayObject *arr_mask;
PyArrayObject *arr_adjacency;
PyArrayObject *arr_state;
PyArrayObject *arr_next_state;

double sum;
int counter_node, n_nodes;

/*  PyArg_ParseTuple
 *  checks if from args, the pointers of type "O" can be extracted, and extracts them
 */

if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OOO:xor_masking_C", &mask, &adjacency, &state))
    return NULL;

/*
 *  The pointer returned by PyArray_ContiguousFromObject is typecasted to
 *  a PyArrayObject Pointer and array is pointed to the same address.
 */

arr_mask = (PyArrayObject *)
PyArray_ContiguousFromObject(mask, PyArray_BOOL, 2, 2);
arr_adjacency = (PyArrayObject *)
PyArray_ContiguousFromObject(adjacency, PyArray_BOOL, 2, 2);
arr_state = (PyArrayObject *)
PyArray_ContiguousFromObject(state, PyArray_BOOL, 2, 2);

if (array == NULL)
    return NULL;

int n_mask_0 = mask->dimensions[0];
int n_mask_1 = mask->dimensions[1];
int n_adjacency_0 = adjacency->dimensions[0];
int n_adjacency_1 = adjacency->dimensions[1];
int n_state_0 = state->dimensions[0];
int n_nodes = n_state_0;
/*
 * if the dimensions don't match, return NULL
 */

bool c_mask[n_nodes][n_nodes];

if (n_mask_0 != n_mask_1 || n_adjacency_0 != n_adjacency_1 ||
n_adjacency_0 != n_mask_0 || n_adjacency_0 != n_adjacency_1) {
    return NULL;
}

/*
 *    The 2D arrays are introduced as follows
 *    array[i][j] = (array->data + i*array->strides[0] + j*array->strides[1])
 */

for (counter_node = 0; i < n_mask; i++){
    *row_start = (array->data + i*array->strides[0]);
}


//Py_DECREF();

//return PyFloat_FromDouble();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't typecast. You just want an accessor function. I'd be surprised if numpy/Python did not come with one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want to look at this: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html

In particular,

```
void* PyArray_GETPTR3(PyObject* obj, <npy_intp> i, <npy_intp> j, <npy_intp> k)
```

and friends. Those are the functions that David Heffernan would be surprised if the API didn't provide.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem and checked out the docs. It has just the prototype, nothing more. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I wouldn't consider this as the answer. It still doesn't answer the question: how do you access the element `array[i][j]`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this answers your question but, to reach your NumPy data in C, you could try to create an iterator to loop over your array in C. It doesn't give you indexing you're after ([i][j]) but it covers the entire array

```
static PyObject *func1(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    PyArrayObject *X;
    int ndX;
    npy_intp *shapeX;
    NpyIter *iter;
    NpyIter_IterNextFunc *iternext;
    PyArray_Descr *dtype;
    double **dataptr;

    PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!", &PyArray_Type, &X);
    ndX = PyArray_NDIM(X);
    shapeX = PyArray_SHAPE(X);
    dtype = PyArray_DescrFromType(NPY_DOUBLE);
    iter = NpyIter_New(X, NPY_ITER_READONLY, NPY_KEEPORDER, NPY_NO_CASTING, dtype);
    iternext = NpyIter_GetIterNext(iter, NULL);
    dataptr = (double **) NpyIter_GetDataPtrArray(iter);
    do {
        cout << **dataptr << endl; //Do something with the data in your array
    } while (iternext(iter));   
    NpyIter_Deallocate(iter);
    return Py_BuildValue(...);
}
```

Comment: I guess this does the typecasting you were trying to avoid :(

Comment: This is a pretty old issue, but thanks for the help! (:
This is how I came up to write that code:
https://gist.github.com/mehmetalianil/6643299

It was C, but the distinction hardly matters here, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you.

http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2003-November/014837.html

Answer (score 1):

This is the dirtiest of all answers here, I guess, but 2 years ago, I ended up implementing this function like this:

Just adding it here for documenting it. If you are reading this, you should check out other solutions, which are better.

https://gist.github.com/mehmetalianil/6643299